# metafizzy flickity select without the animation

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using [metafizzy flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/api.html). Is there a way to select an gallery cell *without* the animation? Unfortunately "initialIndex" doesn't seem to work after the init.

Thanks for any tip, I couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no current API to select a cell immediately, without animation. **+1** this GitHub issue to track any progress: https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity/issues/128